# Improve RealityKit to webRTC workflow

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, realitykit

I have an app that I use `RealityKit`to place AR object and then take 30 screenshot per second from the `ARView`, convert it to `CVPixelBuffer`, and then by combing to the timestamp, i make a `RTCVideoFrame` video frame to publish it. In this process cpu and RAM usage are pretty important. I need your expert suggestion to improve this workflow to reduce CPU and RAM as much as possible

1- I tried to disable the `RealityKit` render options that I don't need

```
  arView.renderOptions = [.disableMotionBlur,
                              .disableDepthOfField,
                              .disablePersonOcclusion,
                              .disableHDR,
                              .disableCameraGrain,
                              .disableFaceMesh]
```

I need environment lighting and shadows, that is why I keep it.
I also set `entity.synchronization = nil`based on the Apple's [suggestions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/reducing-cpu-utilization-in-your-realitykit-app).
Is there anything else that I can do it here?

2- When I get the screenshots, I send the its `CVPixelBuffer` and timestamp through 5 `UIViewControllers` (it's because of the app hierarchy, don't use storyboard) to the `webRTC` model. I don't know how much it's effective on CPU or RAM usage, if I send data with notification and observer directly to the `webRTC` model it's better or the current approach is ok enough.

3- I use this approach to take screenshot from `ARView`, it works on the main thread, do you think I can use a better options? I need to take screenshot from the camera view + the AR object on it

```
// take snapshot from UIView

extension UIImage {
    
    convenience init(view: UIView) {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        if let cgImage = image?.cgImage {
            self.init(cgImage: (cgImage))
        } else {
            self.init()
        }
    }
}
```

4- To take screenshot 30 times per sec, I set a `Timer`, this Timer` is heavy on the cpu or RAM?

```
 timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.03, target: self, selector: #selector(pushFrames), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Is there anyway to do it better?

5- When I take screenshots in the main thread, I created one `DispatchQueue` and I send the data under it

It's a global variable

```
let pushFrameQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "stream.pushFrameQueue")
```

And in the `RealityKit` view controller:

```
    @objc func pushFrames() {

        let image = UIImage(view: arView)
        guard let buffer = pixelBuffer(forImage: image) else { return }
        let currentTimestamp = Date().nanosecondsSince1970

        pushFrameQueue.async { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.pushFrame(buffer: buffer, timestamp: currentTimestamp)
        }
    }
```

In there any way to do it better?

I know, it's a lot of questions together and that I shouldn't do like that, but my job really depend on make it this process better and I have worked on it in the past few months, really need some help here.
Your help with be appreciated.